# Python struct reverse unpack

Tags: python, struct

I'm trying to unpack structure as shown below in this way to get '0123456789'

```
b"\x10\x32\x54\x76\x98"
```

Maybe there is other way then writing own function to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's easier to debug if you use your own function. However, if you want a one line command to turn this into a string you can do like so:

```py
X = b"\x10\x32\x54\x76\x98"

tmp = "".join([hex(i)[:1:-1].zfill(2) for i in X])

print(tmp)
```

`>>> 0123456789`

Basically it turns each byte to hexadecimal (which handles splitting methods), so we split them to read them backward without `"0x"`.

Finally we join them using an empty string separator.

**EDIT**

As pointed by Alain T. I updated the code and added the `zfill()` method to force the string length of each byte to 2 to avoid missing integers like in the example:
`b"\x10\x32\x05\x76\x98"`.

Comment: Thanks for help. I was thinking that maybe i'm doing something wrong trying to unpack it with struct using '!' or '<'.

Comment: This will not work properly if some of your bytes have a leading zero.  For example `b"\x10\x32\x05\x76\x98"`  will output `012356789` instead of `123506789`

Answer (score 0):

You could get an integer mathematically using reduce:

```
from functools import reduce

X = b"\x10\x32\x45\x76\x98"

d = reduce(lambda r,b:r*100+b%16*10+b//16,X,0)

print(d)
# 123546789
```

Or, without libraries using sum() and a comprehension:

```
d = sum( (d%16*10+d//16)*100**i for i,d in enumerate(X[::-1]))

print(d)
# 123546789
```

If you need it to be a string, with leading zero, you can use the format method

```
d = ("{:02x}"*len(X)).format(*X[::-1])[::-1]

print(d)
0123546789
```

or the join function and a comprehension:

```
d = "".join(f"{d%16}{d//16}" for b in X)

print(d)
0123546789
```

For a string output, without leading zeros, you can swap the nibles of each byte before converting them to an integer and then use the hex representation of that integer (this is the fastest string conversion):

```
d = hex(int.from_bytes((b%16*16+b//16 for b in X),"big"))[2:]

print(d)
123546789
```

Performance comparisons:

```
tests = {
"reduce    ": lambda : reduce(lambda r,b:r*100+b%16*10+b//16,X,0),
"from_bytes": lambda : hex(int.from_bytes((b%16*16+b//16 for b in X),"big"))[2:],
"format    ": lambda : ("{:02x}"*len(X)).format(*X[::-1])[::-1],
"join      ": lambda : "".join(f"{d%16}{d//16}" for d in X),
"sum       ": lambda : sum( (d%16*10+d//16)*100**i for i,d in enumerate(X[::-1])),
}


from timeit import timeit

for name,fn in tests.items():
    print(name,fn(),timeit(fn,number=1000000))

reduce      123546789   1.1987413900000001
from_bytes  123546789   1.245261141
format      0123546789  1.517380332
join        0123546789  1.8026392529999997
sum         123546789   2.1293131119999993
```

Comment: Guys, thanks for many examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way to do this just using f-strings and a little bit of arithmetic:

```
X = b"\x10\x32\x54\x76\x98"

for b in X:
    print(f'{b%16}{b//16}', end='')
```

**Output:**

```
0123456789
```

**Note:**

If you need a single string then just build it within the loop instead of printing